# check for hasClass to add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small panel that slides out from the bottom. It has a chevron up icon. I am building a jquery snippet that bring it up (opens it) and closes it but all it must change the chevron from up to down.

The opening and closing is working and the chevron changes when it opens but it doesn't reset back to chevron up when it closes. Something is wrong in my conditional statement.

This is what I have so far

```
<script>
$("#openchat").click(function(){
    $("#floatingmenu").toggleClass("chatbox-open");

    if ($(this).hasClass("chatbox-open")) {
        $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
        $(this).addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    } else if (!$(this).hasClass("chatbox-open")) {
        $(this).addClass("fa-chevron-down");
        $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");    
    }        
});
</script>
```

I am attaching a [**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEzpGM)

BTW, my .chatbox-open class is what opens it and closes it. The other classes are simple font-awesome classes for the icons

Any help please

Comment: You don't need check `if (!$(this).hasClass("chatbox-open"))` simple else block is sufficeint. I would suggest you to simply use `toggleClass()` like `$(this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");`

Comment: Is `chatbox-open` class on both `#openchat` and `#floatingmenu` elements?

Comment: It looks like you are toggling class `chatbox-open` for `#floatingmenu` and checking it for `#openchat`. Anyway, you have to provide mininmalistic sample code to replicate issue, e.g a jsFiddle and all relevant HTML markup in question

Comment: yeah, the solution in the bottom didn't work and toggling fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down does the rick for the chevron toggle but not for the open and close because of the chatbox-open class needs to be present to toggle between open and close. I'll add a jfiddle. Give me a minute to build one quick

Comment: Question is edited. Added a codepen demo

Comment: Just like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogGjxm ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only ever goes into the  `else` because `#openchat` never has its classes toggled elsewhere.

You can just change to this

```
$("#openchat").click(function () {
    $("#floatingmenu").toggleClass("chatbox-open");
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down")
});
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myBeEb

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need that check because if `$(this).hasClass("chatbox-open")` is false it will go straight to else and execute it.

```
<script>
$("#openchat").click(function(){
    $("#floatingmenu").toggleClass("chatbox-open");

    if ( $(this).hasClass("chatbox-open") ){

        $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
        $(this).addClass("fa-chevron-down");

    } else {
            $(this).addClass("fa-chevron-down");
            $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up");    
    }        
});
</script>
```

just remove from else the `if (!$(this).hasClass("chatbox-open"))`

Comment: How does it fix OP's issue?